# Is it possible to convert Visual Basic.NET to JavaScript or a language that runs on Mac

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am trying to convert Visual Basic.NET to JavaScript. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you mean you want to port your code to Java? Javascript has very little of the functionality associated with VB.NET and runs in a completely different environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. The development environment will have more difference than the languages, so it will take more than a direct translation.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), VB.NET can run on a mac.

As for turning it into Javascript--for some things that would be theoretically possible, although I don't know of any tools that actually do so.  More likely, you mean Java, and there you'd have a bit more luck.  You might have to go through C# first..